# How to add only selected values in each row and reaches to the end of the point, stop adding

Tags: javascript, jquery

Thanks in advance.Please guide me how to solve the sum of selected values.This column consists of more than one values in each row.But in a single row it has to be click one value only keep it move on add.The enclosed main table 3 rows and its enclosing again 3 sub values.

In this table I can get selected values result.But it is adding more than 1 value in a single row.When it is reaching at the end of point, its again adding values.

```
<table id="table" border="1">
    <tr><th>Variable</th>
        <th>Score</th></tr>

    <tr><th>CRP (mg/l)</th></tr>

    <tr><td> _> 97</td>
         <td><button  type="button" class="values" value="6">6</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>_>43 < 97</td>
         <td><button class="values" value="4">4</button></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>_>12< 43</td>
        <td><button class="values" value="2">2</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>< 12</td>
        <td><button class="values" value="0">0</button></td>
    </tr>

    <tr><th>NLR</th></tr>

    <tr><td>>9</td>
         <td><button class="values" value="6">6</button></td>      
    </tr> 

    <tr><td> _>43 < 97</td>
        <td><button class="values" value="3">3</button></td>
    </tr> 

    <tr><td>_>12 < 43 </td>
        <td><button class="values" value="1">1</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>< 12 </td>
        <td><button class="values" value="0">0</button></td>

    <tr><th>Procalcitonin(ng/ml)</th></tr>
    <tr><td> >1</td>
        <td><button class="values" value="6">6</button></td>           
     </tr>
    <tr><td>>0.5 to <_1</td>
        <td><button class="values" value="3">3</button></td>
    </tr>

    <tr><td>>0.25 to <_0.5</td>
        <td><button class="values" value="1">1</button></td>
    </tr>

    <tr><td><_0.25 </td>
        <td><button class="values" value="0">0</button></td>
    </tr>           
</table>
 <br><br>

<button type="button" class="total">Total</button>

<button class="clear">Clear</button>

     <script>
        var theTotal = 0;

            $('button').click(function(){
                theTotal = Number(theTotal) + Number($(this).val());
                {
                    $(this).css("border","5px solid #FF0000");/* this is helps to give a text background color*/
                }
            $('.total').text("Total: "+theTotal);        
           });

              $('.total').text("Total: "+theTotal);

    </script>
```

acceptation result is add only single value in each row.At reaches to total value should be stop.And also make clear the values like Total and Clear.

Comment: Could you share the HTML also along with this and what is the expected result. As its not a 100% clear where the problem might be.

Comment: I still am not clear about the problem that you are facing. Check the link which has your code -- > https://jsfiddle.net/apoorvBarwa/vquer70c/1/. When i click on each element the Total count is incremented by the value that is clicked. Is this the desired behavior? Or is the issue something else ?

Comment: Thanks you very much Apoorv.If I will click on 6 number it has to be display 6,then i will click on  4 it has to be select only 4,if I will click 2 it has to be select only 2...and in every main row choose only single value not multiple values.At the end value should be get sum.Unknowingly if i am selected 6 but i need 4 value to be add at the end.So this 6 number i don't want to add.Then it has to be select only 4 not 6.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i think i got what problem you are facing. You want that only one value should be selected from each of the tables and the sum should the value that is selected in each table. Below is the code that i think will work for your requirement. Please let me know if you need any explanation on any part.

Firstly the problem in your code is that you have three tables and from each table you want only one value to be taken but you have the same class referring the elements. A better way would be for them to have different classes so we can differentiate between each table. That is what i have done in the code below.

HTML
    // Added class tableButton to table buttons to differentiate it from other buttons
    
    
      Variable
      Score

```
 <tr>
   <th>CRP (mg/l)</th>
 </tr>

 <tr>
   <td> _> 97</td>
 <td><button type="button" class="tableButton values1" value="6">6</button> 
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>_>43 < 97</td> <td><button class="tableButton values1" 
   value="4">4</button></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td>_>12< 43</td> <td><button class="tableButton values1" 
 value="2">2</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
   < 12</td> <td><button class="tableButton values1" value="0">0</button>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <th>NLR</th>
</tr>

 <tr>
   <td>>9</td>
   <td><button class="tableButton values2" value="6">6</button></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
   <td> _>43 < 97</td> <td><button class="tableButton values2" 
   value="3">3</button></td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td>_>12 < 43 </td> <td><button class="tableButton values2" 
   value="1">1</button></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>
    < 12 </td> <td><button class="tableButton values2" value="0">0</button>
 </td>

  <tr>
    <th>Procalcitonin(ng/ml)</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td> >1</td>
  <td><button class="tableButton values3" value="6">6</button></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>>0.5 to <_1</td> <td><button class="tableButton values3" 
value="3">3</button></td>
</tr>

 <tr>
   <td>>0.25 to <_0.5</td> <td><button class="tableButton values3" 
value="1">1</button></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
   <td>
     <_0.25 </td> <td><button class="tableButton values3" 
value="0">0</button>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
<br><br>

 <button type="button" class="total">Total</button>

 <button class="clear">Clear</button>
```

Javascript Jquery Code:

```
 var theTotal = 0;
 var variables = {}
  //clear button functionality 
 $('.clear').click(function() {
 $.each(variables,function(key,value){
 $("."+key.split(" ")[1]).css("border","#ffffff")
  })
 theTotal = 0
 $('.total').text("Total: " + theTotal);
 })




 $('.tableButton').click(function() {
  {
  var classToRem = ($(this).attr('class'))
  console.log(classToRem)
  variables[classToRem] = Number($(this).val())

    $("."+classToRem.split(" ")[1]).css("border","#ffffff")
   $(this).css("border", "5px solid #FF0000"); /* this is helps to give a 
 text background color*/
 }
 theTotal = Object.keys(variables).reduce((sum,key)=>sum+parseFloat(variables[key]||0),0)


 $('.total').text("Total: " + theTotal);
 });

 $('.total').text("Total: " + theTotal);
```

JSFiddle:
Is this the behavior you are looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/apoorvBarwa/vquer70c/82/

Comment: Thank you for taking the trouble to help me.I do appreciate it.I got accurate result,this is the i am accepting.

Comment: Ok .. glad i could help ... Could you please vote this as accepted answer

Comment: Thank you so much.Yes I was voted.But another issues is there.Clear the sum value  result using clear button.

Comment: @BALARAMA: Sir you upvoted the question that you asked not the answer that i provided. Could you please upvote the answer that i have provided

Comment: No No Sir.I was clicked the left side upward arrow mark i.e This is answer is useful[ ^]

Comment: could you please give me suggestion for clear button.I am just trying to clear the values by using clear button.

Comment: I have updated the answer and the jsfiddle link. Please check this link https://jsfiddle.net/apoorvBarwa/vquer70c/82/. Let me know if this is what you are looking for ... The score of the answer shows 0 though :(

Comment: Yes, I got it Sir.Did you got upvot rank.I want to thank you for taking time out to answer my question.I am sure that you are busy, and  I appreciate you taking the time to respond personally to me.Thank you again

Comment: No i did not get the upvote. Could you please do it again and see what happens

Comment: ok Sir.I will do. I have received this message.Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: Ok. no problem. Then in that case i will get it later on when you cross 15 points

Comment: Hello Mr.Apoorv.Sorry for the again disturbance. This was earlier question,which one u already solved. One value should be selected from each of the tables and the sum should the value that is selected in each table. Along  with now again one more question arises like depending on this results print grade means total result comes >8 infection high, 5 to 8 infection is border line and <5 normal